# DataGridView filter results

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, datagridview, filter

I have this code:

```
Private bs As BindingSource = New BindingSource()
...
bs.Filter = String.Format(Me.DataGridView.SelectedColumns.Item(0).HeaderText.ToString & " LIKE '{0}%'", TextBoxSearchFor.Text)
```

and it works, but after this line of code is done my column selection jumps to Column 1 and does not stay on let's say Column 4. I am using:

```
DataGridView.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullColumnSelect
```

I am not sure how to make the selection stay. Also not clear why filter changes my selection. It should just shrink rows but why would it change selection.